# The application sati(process com.example.sati)has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again

Tags: java, android, eclipse, syntax-error

I am making an app in which there is a splash class containing an image to display         when the app is made to run and another class is made for adding and subtracting a number and it is to be displayed after the image appered first ....

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sati"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />// here shows a warning saying"Not targeting the            latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this         version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details."

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashAct"
//it's the class 'splash' containing an image that shows up on start of an app
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"//it's a class that will appear after 'splash class' 
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.sati.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
following is the code of xml file named splash
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/splash">
</LinearLayout>
```

**Splash.java**

```
package com.example.sati;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle sidra) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(sidra);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);//SPLASH CLASS CODE


}

 } 

   //all above mentioned code is the implementation of ThenewBoston tutorials up to 14
```

**Logcat**

```
    03-24 13:26:23.285: W/dalvikvm(328): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x4001d800)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sati/com.example.sati.SplashAct}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.sati.SplashAct in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.sati-1.apk]
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4 627)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.sati.SplashAct in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.sati-1.apk]
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
    03-24 13:26:23.355: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: can you post the package name of SplashAct

Comment: @Raghunandan it's package name is com.example.sati

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.sati.SplashAct
```

You have

```
public class Splash extends Activity { // Activity Name is Splash not SplashAct
```

So Change this

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashAct"
```

to

```
<activity
    android:name=".Splash"
```

Comment: but why  i am unable to understand the errors shown in the Logcat!!! i am hating it....

Comment: @user3431536 look at the caused by part `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.sati.SplashAct in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.sati-1.apk]`. It says cannot find the Activity @ `com.example.sati.SplashAct`

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest claims there's an activity class `SplashAct` but the code you posted has only `Splash`. Make sure the manifest and code have the same full class names.